# Partial string match

Tags: java, string

I am comparing two values of two different maps and looking for exact and partial matches. I am checking for partial matches using `val1.contains(val2)` but get a `false`. An example of strings I am matching is:

```
val1: Kansas City Athletics  
val2: Athletics
```

why does the `contains()` method not work in this case?

**EDIT**

If my values are interchanged this should still work right? E.g. if

```
val1: Kansas City Athletics

val2: Athletics
```

Here's my code: I am iterating over the values of two maps and comparing values to get exact and partial matches.

```
List<Integer> compareResults = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int i_index = 0;
for (Entry<String, Vector<String>> entry : annotationMap.entrySet()) {///String key: annotationMap.keySet()){
  for (Entry<String, Vector<String>> rageEntry : rageMap.entrySet()) {
   if (entry.getKey().equals("ORGANIZATION")) {
    for (String val : entry.getValue()) {
        recusion:
        for (int i = i_index; i <= rageEntry.getValue().size(); ) {
            String rageVal = rageEntry.getValue().elementAt(i);
            if (val.equals(rageVal)) {
                orgTruePositiveCount++;
                i_index++;
                break recusion;
            } else if (val.contains(rageVal)) {  //|| dataB.get(entryA.getKey()).contains(entryA
                // .getValue())){
                orgTruePositiveCount++;
                i_index++;
                break recusion;
            } else if (!val.contains(rageVal)) {
                orgFalseNegativeCount++;
                i_index++;
                break recusion;
            } else if (!rageVal.contains(val)) {
                orgFalsePositiveCount++;
                i_index++;
                break recusion;
            }

        }
    }
}

if (entry.getKey().equals("PERSON")) {
    for (String val : entry.getValue()) {
        recusion:
        for (int i = i_index; i <= rageEntry.getValue().size(); ) {
            String rageVal = rageEntry.getValue().elementAt(i);

            if (val.equals(rageVal)) {
                perTruePositiveCount++;
                i_index++;
                break recusion;
            } else if (val.contains(rageVal)) {
                perTruePositiveCount++;
                i_index++;
                break recusion;
            } else if (!val.contains(rageVal)) {
                perFalseNegativeCount++;
                i_index++;
                break recusion;
            } else if (!rageVal.contains(val)) {
                perFalsePositiveCount++;
                i_index++;
                break recusion;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. This code prints "contains". `String val1 = "Kansas City Athletics";
        String val2 = "Athletics";

        if (val1.contains(val2)) {
            System.out.println("contains");
        }`

Comment: first of all you said value interchanged but in the example they are the same.
First case should work.
If you interchange them it will not work 
Post code or show what you have tried

Comment: HAve you debugged the code to see what values are reaching that comparision to see if the reason for that 'false' is that the values are not what you expected?

Comment: @Zeromus I think I am encountering the second case. I have to iterate over a bunch of data so I will encounter a lot of cases of the 2nd type. I've updated the question with my code. You'll get a sense of the complexity and what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

It does appear to work in the case you describe - see this simple example:

```
public class ContainsExample {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String val1 = "Kansas City Athletics";
    final String val2 = "Athletics";
    System.out.println(val1.contains(val2));
    System.out.println(val2.contains(val1));
  }
}
```

Running this yields:

```
$ java ContainsExample
true
false
```

Comment: thanks for this. Since I am iterating over two maps and comparing values (vector) I may encounter the second case as well where the 2nd string is longer than the  1st. What's the possible solution for this?

Comment: @serendipity then you have to determine which string is longer and then call `longerString.contains(shorterString);`

Comment: @serendipity or even use an or   If (a.contains(b) || b.contains(a)) , or define your own function and pass a and b as parameters

Comment: @ XtremeBaumer Do I have to write a custom method for that? This code is getting so complex :(

Comment: @Armando SM If you look at my code - I am basically calculating true positive, false positive and false negative counts based on the matches. My count does account for the or statement you mention but for that it needs to update a separate counter. I hope I am able to explain this well enough for you to understand.

Comment: You could externalise to a method:  `private static boolean contains(String val1, String val2) { if (val1 == null || val2 == null) { return false; } return val1.length() >= val2.length() ? val1.contains(val2) : val2.contains(val1); }` or some variation based on the semantics you want to store (magic integer values might not be the best thing though)